# What does setting Thread.Priority = Lowest really mean?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In an effort to speed up the startup of my resource-hungry app, I've moved various startup tasks to background threads and marked those thread with 'Thread.Priority = Lowest`.

However, those low priority threads still execute pretty much in parallel with the application (as it loads its UI), as evidenced by the timeline on the ANTS Profiler.  My understanding was that Lowest meant that the CPU will handle all higher priority threads first, then get the lower priority threads.

Is my understanding flawed?

Comment: Is something stalling the high priority threads?  If every high-priority thread is sitting there waiting for the disk to spin or the network to come back or whatever, then the operating system will cheerfully schedule low-priority threads to fill in the gaps, so as to not waste cycles.

Comment: By way of analogy: you have a number of objects that you have to deliver by truck to a bunch of different places quickly. If the problem is that the truck is spending most of its time at stoplights, then the strategy of "I'm going to give some of those objects to guys on scooters and have them deliver them for me" isn't necessarily solving the problem; the truck might still be sitting at all the same stoplights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The threads may be scheduled with the lowest priority, but they don't wait at the back of the line. They will probably still get enough CPU time slices to gobble up certain resources that are the real bottlenecks, like hard drive access. It really all depends on exactly what you are doing.

Is the initialization computation-intensive? Or web intensive/hard drive intensive. A multi-threading approach is going to be most effective when different tasks use different resources, or to allow computationally intensive operations run without blocking other operations.

A single-threaded approach could feasibly order the tasks to make the application appear to load faster, where-as the multithreaded approach may mean that everyone gets their hands in at the same time, possibly even getting in eachother's way.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what was happening.  Lower priority threads were grabbing resources, forcing the main UI thread to end up waiting around in some cases.  I delayed processing the lower priority items until 5 seconds after the application has loaded and then kick them off (also on a low priority thread).  The application loads a bit faster now.

Answer (score 3):

Lowering the priority doesn't mean that the thread will always be the last one picked to get a time slot. If the lower priority thread hasn't got a time slot for a while, it will be more likely to get one. That way lower priority threads will run slower, but not completely stop.

Also, if the main thread is waiting for something, like for example waiting for the disk drive to return data, the other threads can run in that void. If the main thread does a lot of disk I/O, there will be a lot of holes to run other threads in.

If the CPU has more than a single core, the load will be more evenly distributed between threads. No matter how high priority a thread has, it will still only run on one core.

Comment: priority isn't the right way to go in many cases.   imagine the main thread blocks on a small i/o task, and then a low priority thread opens up some horrible mutex blocking db handle and performs a long-running transaction.  too bad o/s scheduling doesn't also include "i/o suspend/resume".  it's really just the cpu.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to re-engineer your app so that the threads that you're trying to get to wait until the UI is loaded don't actually run at all until after the UI is loaded? This would do what you wish, forcing them to wait until the UI is loaded (because they're not even created/started), whereas the method you're employing causes them to execute less often, but still execute.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the background threads are blocking the main task because they are acquiring some non-cpu resource.  Cpu execution is scheduled between threads, other I/O ops are not.   *For example*: if you're loading records from a DB, you could wind up blocking a lot of processing in the main task.

You can get the best of both worlds with the following:

- Main task sets a signal letting background threads know it's done
- Background threads run in "nice" mode until that signal is received
- Nice mode means deliberately closing transactions & i/o handles, sleeping for some time, waking and resuming long-running tasks every 0.1 seconds... explicitly and frequently yielding to the main thread.  Deliberately inefficient.
- When Nice mode is done, the background threads resume
- The trick is to tune nice mode so that it has no visual impact, while also allowing the background tasks to execute quickly.
- You can go even further, auto-tuning the background yield times based on the running speed of main task operations